# Can I use 'was' twice in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, past-tense, american-english

**For example:**

*"I was salivating on the food he was cooking."*

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds like you're leaning over the food while someone is cooking it and spit is falling into it. Is that what you were imagining?

Comment: Was (Not Was) was an 80s band...

Comment: "It was the best of times, it was the worst of times, it was the age of wisdom, it was the age of foolishness, it was the epoch of belief, it was the epoch of incredulity, it was the season of light, it was the season of darkness, it was the spring of hope, it was the winter of despair" might be one of the most famous beginnings of any book so you're good for about ten was in a sentence.

Answer (score 7):

This is valid.  There is a main clause and a subordinate relative clause.  They both happen to use the same verb.

Your sentence contains a (reduced) relative clause. In English it is possible to form a relative clause without any marker if the word modified by the relative clause is the object of the clause.  It is also optional to include the relativizer word "that"

> the food [that] he was cooking.

"food" is modified (described) by the clause "he was cooking" and "food" is the implied object  (he was cooking the food)

This relative clause is subordinate to the main clause:

> I was salivating on the food [...]

However, note that "salivating on the food" means "my spit was dripping out my mouth and covering the food" ... ewwww.

Comment: Eeeeewwwww. Gross.

Comment: For completeness' sake: it's likely you were salivating _at_ the food rather than _on_ it.

Comment: I think that salivating _over_ the food is most idiomatic. _Over_ in this case does not refer to the physical location, but rather means "while thinking of/experiencing"

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course you can use it twice. There aren't any rules against this.

But here the problem isn't about "was" appearing twice, it's that to make the sentence clear, you have to mention "while" so that people know that it was in the same time when he was cooking.

The best way to express this sentence in this context would be:

> I was salivating on the food while he was cooking.

Comment: I think it's perfectly clear that the salivation occurred while the cooking was in progress. I see no need to reword the sentence for that reason. Now, change "was cooking" to "cooked" and *then* you need something like the word "while".

Comment: This changes the meaning of the sentence: "that" specifies that it's that particular food causing the salivation and implies a physical proximity (eg.: "I'm in the kitchen with him, mouth watering from the aromas") where "while" loses that specificity (eg.: it's compatible with my sitting in the dining room, far removed from the kitchen, possibly considering a wholly different set of food from what he's cooking).